# Get children of a collection of parents with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Category model and Post model with a one-to-many relationship.

I'd like to have all posts for a certain set of categories.

I want the result to be an ActiveRecord object to be able to do further queries.

Right now I'm using `.map` like so

```
categories.map{|c| c.posts.order(position: :asc)}
```

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: How do I get all children of a collection of parents with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 4):

Use embedded query to Posts, as follows:

```
Post.where(category_id: Category.all.pluck(:id)).order(position: :asc)
```

Answer (score -2):

First find all the categories that you are interested and get the ids:

```
category_ids = Category.where('name like ?', '%foo%').pluck(:id)
```

Then just query for the Posts where the `category_id` is included in this list of ids:

```
posts = Post.where(category_id: category_ids)
```

This is a AR object, so you can keep adding `order` or `where` and so on:

```
posts.order(position: :asc)
```

Comment: you forgot to order posts

Comment: Added the order part. Thanks.